# Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: ssl, nginx

I ran a ssl certificate test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and I get a good rating but I see errors next to a few devices for example, under handshake simulation, Android 5.0 and 6.0 have the error message:

> Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure

Does this mean the website won't work on these devices or what does it mean?

My config file looks like this:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;# Requires nginx >= 1.13.0 else use TLSv1.2
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

# Add our strong Diffie-Hellman group
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;

These ciphers are neither supported on Android 6 nor Android 5. Have a look at [SSLLabs report for Android 6.0](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=6.0&key=129) to find out which ciphers are supported. Specifically no ciphers using SHA384 or SHA512 as HMAC are supported.

Comment: Thank you. I also stumbled across this https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html#The_Cipher_Suite which suggested a default sweet for backwards compatibility. It seems to have made that error go away.

Comment: @user8463989: you might use the [server configuration from mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) to adjust the settings to your actual needs.